# What is this plant with yellow flowers on long stems?

Tags: identification

Could anyone name this plant?

Idiotically I forgot its name right after buying it last week. I'm pretty sure it started with a C.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: Mystery flower]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it does begin with a C - its Coreopsis grandiflora, common name Tickseed, a relatively short-lived, very floriferous perennial. Needs a sunny spot, give it some room, it tends to sprawl in its second year if it makes it through the winter (it sometimes doesn't make it through in colder regions).

Comment: Marvellous, thanks for putting me out of my misery Bamboo. I promise to pay more attention next time I'm buying plants!

Comment: Just seen you're in the UK - fingers crossed it makes it through winter, we're supposed to have a bad one this year. I'll believe it when I see it though... got two of these myself, now 2 years old, love 'em for their long flowering period.

Comment: Google wasn't helpful in this case but it did find a lot of images of flowers similar to the one you posted!